# Implements GestureDetector,ScaleGestureDetector,DoubleTapListener on single activity class?

Tags: android

Can we implement OnGestureListener,OnDoubleTapListener and OnScaleGestureListener on single Activity class with ImageView Widget?

I am trying to capture the mouse move, long press, mouse click, double tap, double tap with double fingers and Pinch in and Pinch out to Zoom the Image View. Is it possible single activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [a class can implement multiple interfaces.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html#Footer2)